# False link representation in Markdown file

Tags: formatting, markdown

I've the following lines in a `markdown` file.

```
for i.MX 6UL
```

[image: text as link]
Here i.MX is displayed as a link (in blue text and clickable) but I don't want it to be.

How can I display it as a normal text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `for i\.MX 6UL`. The backslash should escape the autolink.
The other thing you could try is something like `for i.<i></i>MX 6UL` or `for i.<span></span>MX 6UL`. This breaks up the link using basic html.

Comment: `for i\.MX 6UL` doesn't work but this `for i.<i></i>MX 6UL` worked.